# Apache mod_rewrite loaded and working, but not 'seen' by rssLounge application

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm tring to install and configure [RSS Lounge](http://rsslounge.aditu.de/) on my Raspberry PI (Wheezy 3.2.27).
This is what I get when I go to `http://localhost/rsslounge`:

> The Apache module "mod_rewrite" is not loaded

However, the rewrite module is enabled :

```
ab@1234 : sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
    Loaded Modules:
     core_module (static)
     log_config_module (static)
     logio_module (static)
     version_module (static)
     mpm_prefork_module (static)
     http_module (static)
     so_module (static)
     alias_module (shared)
     auth_basic_module (shared)
     authn_file_module (shared)
     authz_default_module (shared)
     authz_groupfile_module (shared)
     authz_host_module (shared)
     authz_user_module (shared)
     autoindex_module (shared)
     cgi_module (shared)
     deflate_module (shared)
     dir_module (shared)
     env_module (shared)
     headers_module (shared)
     mime_module (shared)
     negotiation_module (shared)
     php5_module (shared)
     reqtimeout_module (shared)
     rewrite_module (shared)
     setenvif_module (shared)
     ssl_module (shared)
     status_module (shared)
    Syntax OK
```

Moreover, I followed  [this test](http://www.wallpaperama.com/disp-post19.html)  and the server is behaving correctly so the problem lies on the link between Apache and RSSLounge.

Here is my `/etc/apache2/sites-availables/default` file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                RewriteEngine on
        </Directory>
```

(the rsslounge folder is obviously in `/var/www/`)

What is wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Is RSSLounge in /var/www ? If you install it with a package, it is maybe in /usr/share/rsslounge and your option "RewriteEngine on" is not used.
Put it in the Virtual Host to be available in all your dirs.

Comment: the package is zipped, so you can decompress wherever you want to. I un-zipped it to /var/www/rsslounge (with chown to www-data:www-data).